# same occurrences of word count in pyspark --

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext("local", "first app")
text = sc.textFile("C:\data.txt")
words = text.map(lambda line: str(line)).flatMap(lambda x: x.lower().split(" "))

print(words.top(100))
total_words = words.count()
print(words.count())
wordCount = words.map(lambda x: (x,1)).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)
print(wordCount.top(20))
```

input: `mahi, Mahi, mAhi, maHi, mahI, MAHI, MAhi, MAHi, straw, Straw, STRAW, berry, Berry`
 output: `[('straw,', 3), ('mahi,', 8), ('berry,', 1), ('berry', 1)]`
 But the output should return `[('straw,', 3), ('mahi,', 8), ('berry,', 2)]`. 
I'm new in `pyspark`. Can anyone please help me what's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pyspark` consider the `,` as part of the string, so `berry,` and `Berry` are not the same. You can see it in the results

```
('berry,', 1)
('berry', 1)
```

Split by commas as well

```
text.map(lambda line: str(line)).flatMap(lambda x: x.lower().split(", "))
```